# How to solve Type 'T' cannot be used to index type '{ A: typeof A; B: typeof B; ... }'

Tags: typescript

```js
class A {}
class B {}
class C {}
class D {}


class Example {
  public static ClassesByName = { A:A,B:B,C:C,D:D };

  public stringToClass<
    Hash extends typeof Example.ClassesByName,
    T extends keyof Hash,
  >(className: T) {

    const klass = Example.ClassesByName[className]; //<- Type 'T' cannot be used to index type '{ A: typeof A; B: typeof B; C: typeof C; D: typeof D; }'.

  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&q=253#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8C+AoUkYCFGvVaAwjmuPgCLEokbQCiAHmALYAOIApoitNCwK4AjEAEtg0CABcwE0YVIR2ETAE8Acs04BeRHABcsADSZdmAwV0EDZXRSQBuKj35DZkgE7CAdgHMAKgHsCeQAebh5oAAlIAAtodnoJdk8AExgJZRZ2fwAzOkZWDgA6IIxFFXUmdgMwnl84hKTU6ABrdmUcyJjqngA+AAo8CAr2XWhfAEouGuhgf09JFvlobQZmNnZi+TK1DQBtQeGAXTtoAHpT4IBaMYzOAHJfO5mwT09-CWgBTj4FZOgJfzQLzJeL-W7QO4IPRgzIdWAnYwwrK5TAncxIjoEE7WDG5MgnJB3QqOaCoVBAA)

I get this error:

```
Type 'T' cannot be used to index type '{ A: typeof A; B: typeof B; C: typeof C; D: typeof D; }'.
```

on this line:

```js
const klass = Example.ClassesByName[className];
```

`className` is of type `T` which extends `keyof Hash`. And `Hash` extends `typeof Example.ClassesByName`.

Everything is connected, so why is TypeScript telling me I can not use `className` to index `Example.ClassesByName` and how do I fix it?

Comment: ① Oh and hey, this is the opposite of your other question; please [edit] both so that you only have code relevant to the problem you're asking about in the current question. It might matter to you that the full code exist, but for future readers of SO, it's just a distraction.

Comment: ② Your problem here is that there's no reason for `Hash` to be generic; all you're doing is allowing someone to pass in a more specific type with extra keys, and then you're indexing with a key that doesn't apply (which is the error) see [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Wzq8km). Does that fully explain the situation? If so I'll write up an answer after you clean up the question to make it more appropriate.

Comment: Thank you, yes it does explain the situation. Please write an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `stringToClass()` is too [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).  By having `H extends typeof Example.ClassesByName`, you are allowing it to be *more specific* than that type, and therefore have possibly additional keys.  That is, someone can call

```
const whoops = Object.assign({ a: 123 }, Example.ClassesByName);
const instance = new Example();
const hmm = instance.stringToClass<typeof whoops, "a">("a");
```

So `whoops` has an extra property in it at key `a`, but it's still assignable to `typeof Example.ClassesByName`. So you can pass its type as the first type argument to `stringToClass()`, and therefore pass `"a"` as its second type argument (since it's a valid key of that type) and so `className` can be `"a"`.  But inside `stringToClass()`:

```
public stringToClass<
  H extends typeof Example.ClassesByName,
  K extends keyof H,
>(className: K) {
  const klass = Example.ClassesByName[className]; // error!
}
```

you're not indexing into something *generic* with `className`, you're just indexing into `Example.ClassesByName`. The compiler has no idea if `className` of type `K` will actually be a key of `Example.ClassesByName`, since it has no idea what possible extra keys someone will pass in for `H`.  So it's an error.

---

The fix here is to only make `stringToClass()` generic in `K`, which is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `keyof typeof Example.ClassesByName`.  That means `K` will *definitely* be an index for `Example.ClassesByName` and your implementation will compile:

```
public stringToClass<
  K extends keyof typeof Example.ClassesByName,
>(className: K) {
  const klass = Example.ClassesByName[className]; // okay
}
```

And now you can't call it the bad way anymore, since `"a"` is just not a key of `Example.ClassesByName`, and you have no way to pass in `typeof whoops` or anything else:

```
const instance = new Example();
const hmm = instance.stringToClass<"a">("a"); // error!
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&q=253#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-13I1mq12p0AOKG3qzPki2PTPofPQBb5GXA49YQLZyp1IE7nS7OG53B5PZRvImbpbN-57kEfQakyHQ2EwGl01Ed5FUVXKU90TZomXmVklU5aBuXXN9+QrYVNCdYD41xA98WaRU1jlVUNS1MgqTATZ3nmdxzTmRCbXtI0YEOV0PS9H0oD9AMg1DSNo0LDEQJlTC5THVMkLrMAG1zfMeOLThSyotNoCrGsMwrMSOkxJtwmfNsR2HQdkwIiFqBkagAEJxyAA)

Comment: That's a thorough and very useful explanation. Together with your explanation of the meaning of the `extend` keyword https://stackoverflow.com/a/77974869/2199605 It all clicked in my mind. Thank you!