# Why doesn't my conditional type work as I expect?

Tags: typescript

```js
class A {}
class B {}
class C {}
class D {}

//! How/Why does that even work?
type MyObjectType<T extends (keyof Hash), Hash> = (keyof Hash) extends T ? null : Hash[T];

class Example {
  public static ClassesByName = { A: A, B: B, C: C, D: D };

  public stringToClass<
    Hash extends typeof Example.ClassesByName,
    T extends keyof Hash,
  >(className: T): MyObjectType<T, Hash> {
    throw new Error("unimplemented");
  }
}

const instance = new Example();
const klassA = instance.stringToClass("A"); //<- Expected: klassA is "typeof A" as wanted
const klassB = instance.stringToClass("B"); //<- Expected: klassB is "typeof B" as wanted
const klassZ = instance.stringToClass("Z"); //<- Expected: klassZ is null, wrong parameter triggers ts error as wanted
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&q=253#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8C+AoUkYCFGvVaAwjmuPgCLEoD0VAhNABID2A7lQOoAWAntACZMApjAAunMCOiCAboIB20FkwBOAawD8KEdwAOg6AFluAeQBGAK0HARAFV2CAPDakAPEfL4wAFKsHcmAGaMkJwAlAA0wRCcAHzQALzQPn6BUWGu7nKe0M7q0HIAriAg0ABcaQDaNgC6ANwoJBjQAKIuYAC2OiD6CCjQ0DoFpiAAlsDQECISY4SkEMKY3AByHfqJCHDlsJGY5ZiRBOUEkWTlFEj1fQNDo+OTyiNyAOY2TARzDlf9DCEZHqL2VKtDpdQQAOneGAWy1W4S+OT+WRgvn8QR+0Th-RiXjwEBW7UE5RsoXKRjMlmsdj0Tki6NiiHhYmUrHyghYLWUzOUXgARAU5CNOt0CXJ3HweaF6v1UKg0Ew5JNoI9JmA5MA1qz2cChYIvJK5QrJKo5vBEsqpmrwfdHi83nNebAJbVoDQHABaFouPTWQR8crGjDwEYwHnaPSpR3QSCKVVig2KgNQbBmw2q9Vg63PV6QqC8zBOl1Ud2e71i-1zbDB6ChwFBfNRmAsWO++NGuYALQSStTlozIgeWbtGF57YLro9rVLvvLGE7VcKxUiLGZzwGYGUq3cymg-ZGTyegmUohgh65DZjopbQA)

It looks like my conditional type works in reverse of the documentation

TypeScript's [documentation for conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) states:

```js
SomeType extends OtherType ? TrueType : FalseType;
```

Therefore my logic is: if keys in `Hash` includes key (`T`), then `Hash[T]` otherwise `null`; so I wrote:

```js
type MyObjectType<T extends (keyof Hash), Hash> = (keyof Hash) extends T ? Hash[T] : null;
```

But that didn't word and reversing `TrueType : FalseType` makes it work perfectly:

```js
type MyObjectType<T extends (keyof Hash), Hash> = (keyof Hash) extends T ? null : Hash[T];
```

Why does it work in reverse?

Comment: Why would you make the `toString` method of your classes *static*? Also, having a runtime mapping of classnames to classes is usually indicative of an OO-antipattern.

Comment: @JaredSmith This is a example, the `static toString`  is only there so `console.log('klassA', klassA );` would display something easy to read in.

Comment: ① Please [edit] the code here so the only problem you're asking about is present. Are we supposed to worry about `Example.ClassesByName[className]` being a compiler error? If not, please remove it so we can ignore it. If so, then make it clear that this is your problem. ② Your conditional type only "works" accidentally and is unnecessary, just replace it with `Hash[K]`. If you *must* do a check, then change it to `K extends keyof Hash` as in [this version](//tsplay.dev/Na5eEN). If that meets your needs I'll write an answer, but you've got quite a few extraneous problems to clean up first.

Comment: @jcalz It does meet my need! Thank you! Could you provide some explanation or links explaining why `K extends keyof H` works that way? In my head `K` is a single value and `keyof H` is an array, so it should be the other way around...

About the compiler error at `Example.ClassesByName[className]`, I posted another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77974585/typescript-how-to-solve-type-t-cannot-be-used-to-index-type-a-typeof-a-b.

Comment: I had to do something similar once. [Code](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-video-player/blob/308c2ad26d865d725cd626bf70a4d429b61b25fd/libs/mintplayer-ng-vidyard-player/src/lib/extensions.ts#L6)

Comment: I'm writing up an answer but could you please remove the implementation with the issue for the other question?  Just like `throw` or something in there, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wQjlJN) so that it doesn't distract.

Comment: @jcalz I will update both questions accordingly tomorrow morning and ping you afterwards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're confused about the meaning of the `extends` keyword both in [generic constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) and in [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html).  If you have two types `X` and `Y`, then saying `X extends Y` means that if you have a value of type `X`, you are allowed to assign it to a variable of type `Y`, but not necessarily vice versa.

So if you want to say that you have a value of type `K` which should be assignable to a variable of type `keyof H`.  Like, imagine `H` is `{a: string, b: number, c: boolean}`.  Then you have a value of type `K` which should be assignable to a variable of [the union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `"a" | "b" | "c"`.  This will let `K` be `"a"`, or `"b"`, or `"a" | "b"`, but if it's something like `"z"` then it won't work.  In this case, you need to say `K extends keyof H`.  If you say the opposite, that `keyof H extends K`, you're saying that `K` needs to accept *all* of `"a" | "b" | "c"`, at least.  But that's not what you're trying to do.

If you still feel that `extends` should work the other way, it probably means you're thinking of object types and not key types.  Objects are *contravariant* in their key types, meaning that if `A extends B`, then `keyof B extends keyof A`.  See [Union and Intersection of types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59722333/2887218) for a similar issue.

---

So your type

```
type MyObjectType<K extends keyof H, H> = (keyof H) extends K ? null : H[K];
```

only ever "works" accidentally.  Since `K extends keyof H`, the only way `(keyof H) extends K` is if `K` and `keyof H` are the same.  Meaning that `K` has to be the union of all keys in `H`.  This usually doesn't happen; if you call `stringToClass()` with one of the valid keys, then `K` will be just that key, and the check `(keyof H) extends K` will *fail*, and you'll get `H[K]`.  On the other hand, if someone calls `stringToClass()` with something invalid, the inference for `K` will fail, it will fall back to the full constraint `keyof H`, the check `(keyof H) extends K` will *succeed*, and you'll get `null`.  That this happens to kind of work is a combination of accidents, and we should just rewrite your type correctly.

---

So we want `K extends keyof H` and not vice versa.  And that means you could write `type MyObjectType<K extends keyof H, H> = H[K]` directly without a conditional type at all. After all, you've already constrained `K extends keyof H`.  If you must do a check because you want to return `null` for bad inputs, then you should unconstrain `K` to allow such inputs, and do the conditional check the right way:

```
type MyObjectType<K, H> = K extends keyof H ? H[K] : null
```

And then `stringToClass()` looks like

```
class Example {
  public static ClassesByName = { A: A, B: B, C: C, D: D };

  public stringToClass<
    H extends typeof Example.ClassesByName,
    K,
  >(className: K & keyof H): MyObjectType<K, H> {
    throw new Error("unimplemented");
  }
}
```

where again I removed the constraint from `K` (so that `MyObjectType<K, H>` actually allows it), and to preserve the error when you call it with a bad `classname` input, I [intersected](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `K` with `keyof H`.

---

Let's test it out:

```
const instance = new Example();
const klassA = instance.stringToClass("A"); // okay
// const klassA: typeof A
const klassB = instance.stringToClass("B"); // okay
// const klassB: typeof B
const klassZ = instance.stringToClass("Z"); // error!
// ---------------------------------> ~~~
// const klassZ: null
```

Looks good.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&q=253#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G9oAcCuAjEBLY0IBcx8dp8B7AZXwCcsA7AcwAoBKRaagU31WrugDkACU4gQZaADNqZALZwB0AL7KAUKEgwAQuzSYSBIiXJVajVuy48+gkWInS50LYpVL14KNADCujNlxDYlwTGnpmNiQrXn5hUXEpGXlvVzUNLwARP31AwmDSSjDzSI5uGNt4hyToDNT3VVV8AE9kTmgAWSaAeXQAK05gfAAVFs4AHgBpABpoIQA+aABeaAnoTgAPfE46ABMYAGtOJrJJWegAflmAbQmAXWgALmg6VDEG9JgAUXWwWWQQNoIVTQFD+Ax5EjeTwQTgQLRNAByvzayyQsCesBmWieWhm3ie3hmGSeWSUAG4GiC9AE8EUGEMyFDNGNgSCzhstrsYM1WidoN9fv9OAA6JlQWHwpGyThTVkg6asuZMD5SzhPVYAMmgh2OpyELCenR6-UGI1akxm80QctIAAsZAB3Z6cJ2fagyahMABEqDoWD+AOldC2Oy9LApIPc9WAZDoBGg9EMdGAKOdrp+Ac4rApMbj+G10Pgy0ThGTIoIZnpjOh3tgYbJ0AA9I3oGR9mAmqpm9Bc-H9oWnjzOHzYOpY33oTpi3mwGXhRXwgyxRBvVp602W22O12W738-3NNjSKM+Vox3mC5oAFpLBMzucLxhLmteq-r7ucd1kagAQh30AAWiA4CQNAsDwNAhYAD8YP-PdLygK8nheN4gA)

Comment: Your assumption about my confusion about the meaning of the `extends` keyword was correct. Your answer together with the links you provided helped me a lot, especially the one about `generic constraints`. Thank you.